# How to show data according v-for index outside loop

Tags: vue.js

Design:
[image: design]

My process:
[image: My process]

I want to show different data when changing different slide. However the v-for loop is swiper-slide, I can't put loop the data inside at the same time. I have to loop the data in another loop. It would list all, but not one by one according to each slide. How I can print as the design? I do some research, seems that need to use slideChange(). There are almost no sample, could anyone tell me how to do this?

Also, it seems that there are something wrong with the loop='true'. The autoplay will stuck if pressing next button at last image and sometimes it can not show the next-img. I would be grateful, if you could also take a look for me.

```
  <div class="title">Highlighted Programmes</div>

  <swiper
    :loop="true"
    :slidesPerView="'auto'"
    :centeredSlides="true"
    :spaceBetween="30"
    :autoplay="{
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    }"
    :pagination="{
      clickable: true,
    }"
    :navigation="true"
    :modules="modules"
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <!-- Loop Img -->
    <swiper-slide v-for="(program, index) in programs" :key="index">
      <img :src="program.image" />
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper>

  <!-- Loop Text -->
  <div class="list" v-for="(program, index) in programs" :key="index">
    <div>
      <div class="series-name">
        {{ program.series }}
      </div>

      <div class="song-name">
        {{ program.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import { Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper/modules";

export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    /* Swiper Data */
    const programs = ref([
      {
        image: "src/image/swiper-2/highlight1.jpg",
        series: "World Music Series:",
        name: "A Cultural Journey through World Music” Lecture Demonstration",
      },
      {
        image: "src/image/swiper-2/highlight2.jpg",
        series: "Series 2",
        name: "222",
      },
      {
        image: "src/image/swiper-2/highlight3.jpg",
        series: "Series 3",
        name: "333",
      },
    ]);
    return {
      modules: [Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation],
      programs,
    };
  },
};
</script>


<style scoped>
.title {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;

  color: var(--main-orange-orange-900, #6b2a23);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 3.4375rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.list {
  padding-top: 2.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.series-name {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
.song-name {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
.swiper-slide-active {
  width: 47.5625rem;
  height: 26.94513rem;
}

/* --------------- Swiper overwrite --------------- */
.swiper /deep/ .swiper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper /deep/ .swiper-slide img {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.swiper /deep/ .swiper-slide swiper-slide-active {
  width: 47.5625rem;
  height: 26.94513rem;
}

.swiper /deep/ .swiper-slide swiper-slide {
  width: 34.1875rem;
  height: 19.35494rem;
}

.swiper /deep/ .swiper-button-prev {
  color: var(--light-gold, #857056); /* arrow sign */
  /* position: absolute; */

  /* circle  */
  border-width: 2.5px; /* edge thickness */
  border-color: #857056;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding-top: 2.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.3rem;
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  padding-right: 2.6rem;
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.swiper /deep/ .swiper-button-next {
  color: var(--light-gold, #857056); /* arrow sign */
  /* position: absolute; */

  /* circle  */
  border-width: 2.5px; /* edge thickness */
  border-color: #857056;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding-top: 2.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.3rem;
  padding-left: 2.6rem;
  padding-right: 2.2rem;
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
</style>
```

Comment: `@slideChange` event on the `Swiper` component could help you. Every time the slide has changed, you can identify the switched item from the even and show whatever you want according to the active element

Comment: I only find this sample(https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events), but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I've added an answer using the events method. Please check it out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<template>` tag for the v-for loop

```
  <swiper-slide v-for="(program, index) in programs" :key="index">
    <img :src="program.image"/>
    <div>
      <div class="series-name">
        {{ program.series }}
      </div>

      <div class="song-name">
        {{ program.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </swiper-slide>
```

Comment: It is not work.

Comment: Updated. You can put the div into swiper-slide

Comment: Of course I tried this method, I know it can loop all stuff in one loop. However, the result is not what I want. It will show data in all slide, but not only the active slide. Also, the display position won't be outside the swiper-wrapper.

Comment: You could use a `v-if="index === activeIndex"` on the info part of your slide.

Comment: It would only show the 1st slide data, and the data is display in the swiper not outside.

Comment: Okay then you don't need a loop for the texts. Just get the program at activeIndex then render it.

It's better if you can put a quick demo.

Comment: I want to insert a demo too, if I could. However, it don't support import the modles(my swiper).

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the Swiper events can help:

What is done here?

- an `activeIndex` ref is initialized with 0. `0` because the swiper module initializes the swiper with the first activeIndex as `0`
- now we watch every time the slide is changed using the `slideChange` event
- every time the slide is changed, the `activeIndex` ref is updated from the swiper data.
- now outside the swiper, your extra content is rendered using `programs[activeIndex]`, because now `activeIndex` gives the position of the program that is currently active in the swiper.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper/modules';
import "swiper/css/bundle"

const activeIndex = ref(0);

const onSwiper = (swiper: any) => {
  activeIndex.value = swiper.activeIndex;
};

const onSlideChange = (swiper: any) => {
  activeIndex.value = swiper.activeIndex;
};
const programs = ref([
  {
    image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/06/30/18/56/butterfly-142506_1280.jpg",
    series: "World Music Series:",
    name: "A Cultural Journey through World Music” Lecture Demonstration",
  },
  {
    image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/08/18/01/butterfly-8177925_1280.jpg",
    series: "Series 2",
    name: "222",
  },
  {
    image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/03/01/00/55/flowers-19830_1280.jpg",
    series: "Series 3",
    name: "333",
  },
]);
</script>
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <swiper :modules="[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]" :slides-per-view="1" :space-between="50"
      @swiper="onSwiper" @slideChange="onSlideChange" navigation :pagination="{ clickable: true }">
      <swiper-slide v-for="slide in programs" :key="slide.image">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <img :src="slide.image" alt="slide image" />
        </div>
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
    <div class="extra-content">
      <h2>{{ programs[activeIndex].series }}</h2>
      <h3>{{ programs[activeIndex].name }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope this helps.